# Switching kicker solenoid with an idea out of the box

Tags: dc, coil, solenoid

From my previous posting some may know I am planning to make a kicker solenoid.

The circuit specs:

- Coil - 3.5 Ω, 3.4 mH (inductance)
- Capacitor 1000 μF, 450 V
- DC booster up to 410 V
- 12 V DC battery
- Diode 1000 V, 1 A
- **Switch** ????

I will use 200 V: 200/3.5 = 57 Ω

The solenoid will work for a few milliseconds and then turn off. A diode will be connected across the coil to prevent the back EMF.

The main problem is switching the coil. Options for switching the coil are limited:

**Relay** - will fail as there is no relay rated for 200 V and 100 A (even mechanical switches are not recommended here).

**SCR** - high-rated ones are not available in my country and it will not turn off automatically (of course GTO thyristors aren't available here too).

**MOSFET** - some people use it, but theoretically it will fail with my project.

**IGBT** - not enough sources about this, and I have no experience with IGBTs, it looks like a combination between a MOSFET and a BJT.

So I thought it should work in a very simple way:

Take two bars of plastic or wood and connect both of them with a spring. Each bar carries the wires, one from the coil, and one from a capacitor. Then press on first bar to touch the other one.

Since there is a diode there will be no arcing or spike and the coilgun will work.

[image]

[image]

Will it work? Or am I going mad?

Comment: So, it sounds like you're talking about making your own switch? Why not buy an appropriately rated contactor? I think there are kilovac relays that can meet your needs, if you can afford them.

Comment: @Hearth i do not think AC relay will work with Dc current

Comment: Look at the Kilovac EV200 series. Ought to do the trick, if you can afford it.

Comment: Oh it's so expensive for me, and other problem those relays not available in my country, even i tried to ship one the customs will be so high 

Comment: If the idea is to dump the capacitor charge into the solenoid, then the diode won’t do much as all the energy will be expended. For 200V, 100A you want a contactor, not a relay. They’re a common industrial electrical item that you could get from a junk yard for a few $$$

Comment: How many times do you need the switch to operate? Arching will cause pitting and carbonization on the contact points, it won't last long.

Comment: @Kartman meaning diode will slow down the current to solenoid?

Comment: @Mattman944 even with diode will be there arching?

Comment: You will get arcing when the contacts first connect as a lot of current will flow. Once the capacitor has discharged, there is no current, so nothing for the diode to do and no arc when the contacts open.

Comment: But there is a good thing even this switch damage it can be completely replaced with new one since it cost very cheap

Comment: Note the peak current is short lived, so many scrs with a lower continuous rating will survive a short term peak. The datasheets should tell you this. As well, you have a large duty cycle ie: short on time, long off time.

Comment: @Kartman SCRs are good solution but the problem i faced SCRs do not turn themseles off but will remain on until the current drops below the minimum holding current, and with each discharging of the capacitor will start to charge rapidly means the SCR will not turn off

Comment: I proposed a solution to the SCR turn-off issue in one of your previous questions. I will post an improved version here.

Comment: There is always arcing, on make and on break. You may be able tor educe, but not eliminate it.

Comment: will your power supply appreciate the short circuit that is applied to it?  You charge up your capacitor then connect the solenoid. The current with then rise, the solenoid will saturate and pull current that is limited by the DC resistance of the solenoid. At some point the capacitor will expend all of it's energy and the power supply is looking at a short circuit. The voltage and current will be near zero, so the scr should let go. At some point the power supply should recover and begin to charge the capacitor again. This should be easy to simulate and give you some hard evidence.

Comment: @Kartman This mean the SCR will turn off after the cap discharge in this circuit

Answer (score 3):

An SCR is a better solution than a homemade switch. SCRs have huge surge capabilities, about 10X their continuous rating. A 10 amp SCR would probably work.  Get a 20 amp or higher if you can.

You can solve the SCR turn off by turning off the HV supply. When I built something similar to this years ago, I used a single double pole switch: ON-OFF-Momentary_ON. Unfortunately, not a common switch. But, two switches will work also. Open SW2 before closing SW1.

Some values are approximate, you may need to fine-tune.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj5TQx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I have thyristor (btw69-1200) 50A and up to 580A peak on-state current, it will work, but i can not use two switches or on-off-on switch ( push button only) with the push button i will send a pulse to the gate from separated battery, so thyristor will start but the question here after the cap discharge will the thyristor turn off or no? Note after the cap discharge will start charging immediately

Comment: You need to turn off SW2 before firing the SCR. Then everything will discharge and the SCR will turn-off.

Comment: this switch can not be existed in my project, i can not add switch there or between cap and thyristor

Comment: There are MOSFETS that will work if you can access them where you are. They are moderately expensive, but not excessive.

Answer (score 0):

After researching I found that a SCR (thyristor) is the best way to switch the solenoid.

But the problem is that I don't want to use a toggle switch to switch off the power supply current to the thyristor.

I just need one push button - just one press to:

trigger the thyristorstop the current to stop the thyristor

To solve this I got two limited switch as the following in the schematic:

One connected as a NC so when I press the current stop (SW2).

One connected as NO so when I press tigger the thyristor (SW3).

[image]

These two buttons connected by adhesive tape so I can press both at once.

[image]

And yes it worked, the thyristor tiggered then stop with only one press.

Note the SW1 I added to turn power off if the SW2 did not work.

Thank you @mattman944 for your help.