# Thyristor external power supply

Tags: dc, coil, solenoid, thyristor

I am trying to make a kicker solenoid. My circuit is:

- 12 V battery connect to DC step up booster 300 V
- diode
- thyristor BTW69-1200 with external circuit (battery 1.5 V - resistor 1/4 W, 39 Ω)
- capacitor 1000 μF - 450 V
- solenoid coil (3.6 Ω)

[image]

This external small circuit (battery 1.5 V - resistor) is here to trigger the gate.

Max Vg = 1.5 V
Max Ig = 50 mA

I am confused about this small circuit voltage and current. Will this small circuit have the whole circuit voltage and current, which will burn the resistor and thyristor? Or will it have its own current and voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method of firing the gate should work. Be sure to open SW3 first!

If you don't fully understand a circuit, simulate it. Use the CircuitLab simulator linked to this site.

This simulator doesn't have a working SCR, so I substituted a switch. The peak current is 62 A, well within the  peak rating of your SCR.

Finding a switch rated for 300 V won't be easy. That is why I said to put the switch on the primary side of your 12v to 300V booster. You previously said that this wasn't possible due to constraints beyond your control.

Also see my previous answer to your 1st question: [Switching kicker solenoid with an idea out of the box](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/633571/switching-kicker-solenoid-with-an-idea-out-of-the-box)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIvVcG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you explanation, i need to clearify something with the scr, i will wire the gate with resistor and 1.5v battery and wiring the negative end of the 1.5v battery to cathode so what will be the volatge there, will be 1.5v?

Comment: The gate of the SCR looks like a diode. So, the gate will have about 0.7 volts when the switch is pushed.